# Laravel 4 500 Internal Server Error when query database

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, query-builder

I am using code below

`$users = DB::table('users')->find(1);`

And I got **500 Internal Server Error**
but when I use

`$users = DB::table('users')->get();`

It works, what is the issue with first code snippet?

Comment: Please, provide some more details that we can better help you

Comment: check your error log to see what's logged in there..

Comment: i just create some route like this Route::get('/', function()
{       
       $users = DB::table('users')->find(1);
        
        return $users;
       
      
   
});

Answer (score 1):

Using `find()` with query builder, e.g. `DB::table(...)->find()` only works if you have primary key (or a column) named "id". Do you have an "id" column?

If not you'll need to use:

```
$users = DB::table(...)->where('your_primary_key', '=', 1)->first();
```

---

**Reference:** [framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1334-L1337):

```
public function find($id, $columns = array('*'))
{
    return $this->where('id', '=', $id)->first($columns);
}
```